# How can I parse JSON such that if the structure is not as I intended it gracefully fails?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, deserialization

Reference: https://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2018-05-25-kotlin-gson-nullability.html

This article talks about one of the shortcomings of GSON with Kotlin. If we have a data class like this and try to break it:

```
data class User(
    val email: String,
    val firstName: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val json = """{
    "email": null
    }"""
  val gson = Gson()

  println(gson.fromJson(json, User::class.java).email)
}
```

as soon as we parse it and use the `email` field we'll return a `NullPointerException`. This is the intended behavior of GSON.

Is there a library out there that can give me an error like `IllegalStateException` and validate which field should be nullable? Or, is there a way to work around `Moshi` or `GSON` or any other JSON library so that I can get errors like that?

Comment: `data class User(
    @SerializedName("email") val email: String,
    @SerializedName("firstName") val firstName: String)`

Comment: have a look to jackson https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs

Answer (score -1):

Gson doesn't give NullPointerException if a field is missing.It just ignores the missing fields of the object. For more details i would request you to share error log with exception and the code.

Comment: If I deserialize the example JSON I provided and try calling `User.email`, I'll receive a NullPointerException, but since I'm using Kotlin, that should be an illegal state because I didn't define my property as optional.